# Caliburn Micro phonecontainer injecting service with generic type, always null

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, caliburn.micro

I am trying to register a service on the phone container that uses generics.

```
public class JsonWebClient<TResult> : IJsonWebClient<TResult>
```

I am registering like this:

```
protected override void Configure()
{
    _container = new PhoneContainer(RootFrame);

    _container.RegisterPhoneServices();
    _container.Singleton<MainPageViewModel>();
    _container.PerRequest<LoginViewModel>();


    _container.RegisterPerRequest(typeof(IJsonWebClient<>), "jsonwebclient", typeof(JsonWebClient<>));
}
```

Then I have a service (Signup service), where I inject `JsonWebClient` in constructor

```
public SignupService(IJsonWebClient<UserDto> webClient)
{
    _webClient = webClient;
}
```

My problem is that `webClient` is always null.

Comment: Yes, all my services are resolved by container, everything not using generics is working perfectly fine. So im suspecting what nemesv is suggesting, that Caliburn.Micro does not support it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the `SimpleContainer` inside Caliburn.Micro doesn't support open generics registration.

So you need to register your `IJonWebClient<T>` for every `T`

```
_container.RegisterPerRequest(
    typeof(IJsonWebClient<UserDto>),
    "jsonwebclientuser", 
    typeof(JsonWebClient<UserDto>));
_container.RegisterPerRequest(
    typeof(IJsonWebClient<OtherDto>), 
    "jsonwebclientother", 
    typeof(JsonWebClient<OtherDto>));
```

Note: If you are not resolving by key the `key` string should be `null` when calling `RegisterPerRequest`. So it should look like this:

```
_container.RegisterPerRequest(
    typeof(IJsonWebClient<UserDto>),
    null, 
    typeof(JsonWebClient<UserDto>));
```

Or you can some other IoC container which supports open generics like Ninject or Autofac.

Comment: I was sort of expecting this, not what i wanted to hear though :)

Comment: Did not know string should be null, thanks! Tried registering for every T and it works fine. Guess that supports your answer as well. Thanks.